# Sending an email using php shows a blank page

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to collect some informations from an html form and send them to an e-mail using php.
but all i get is a blank page. i looked to similar questions but i couldn't find the problem.
this is my code:

```
<?php



     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $Fname=$_POST['First'];
         $Lname=$_POST['Last'];
         $email=$_POST['email'];
         $code=$_POST['countryCode'];
         $phone=$_POST['phone'];
         $Pname=$_POST['ProjectName'];
         $Ptype=$_POST['ProjectType'];
         $Pdisplay=$_POST['ProjectDisplay'];
         $Powner=$_POST['ProjectOwner'];
         $Plang=$_POST['ProjectLang'];
         $Gender=$_POST['Gender'];
         $Vitess=$_POST['Vitesse'];
         $Style=$_POST['Style'];
         $Duration=$_POST['Duration'];
         $Script=$_POST['Script'];
         $Cmnt=$_POST['Cmnt'];

        $to='myAdredd';
        $subject='Order';
        $message="First Name: ".$Fname." "."Last Name: ".$Lname." "."\n"."E-mail: ".$email."\n"."Phone: ".$code." ".$phone."\n"."Project Name: ".$Pname."\n"."Project Type: ".$Ptype."\n"."Project Display: ".$Pdisplay."\n"."Owner: ".$Powner."\n"."Language: ".$Plang."\n"."Gender Voice: ".$Gender."\n"."Vitess: ".$Vitess."\n"."Style: ".$Style."\n"."Duration: ".$Duration."\n"."Script: "."\n\n".".$Script."."Message: ".$Cmnt."\n";

        $headers="From: ".$email;


         if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
             echo "sent";
         }else{
             echo "problem ";
        }


 }



?>
```

after submitting the form i don t see neither of : "sent" or "problem"

the site is hosted on bluehost

**this is my first time ever using php**

Comment: Then it means there is error in code. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-errors-in-php-file

Comment: Or maybe your _POST does not contain `submit` variable?

Comment: If it's PHP7, then add `?? '[Not provided on line ' . __LINE__ . ']'` after each `=$_POST[...]`

Comment: Thank you, it s working now .

Comment: Please tell us what helped you, what was the issue?

Comment: the php code was correct,i made a typing mitake in the `submit` button on the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try` `catch` for identify the error in script like-:

```
<?php
    try{
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $Fname=$_POST['First'];
            $Lname=$_POST['Last'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $code=$_POST['countryCode'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];
            $Pname=$_POST['ProjectName'];
            $Ptype=$_POST['ProjectType'];
            $Pdisplay=$_POST['ProjectDisplay'];
            $Powner=$_POST['ProjectOwner'];
            $Plang=$_POST['ProjectLang'];
            $Gender=$_POST['Gender'];
            $Vitess=$_POST['Vitesse'];
            $Style=$_POST['Style'];
            $Duration=$_POST['Duration'];
            $Script=$_POST['Script'];
            $Cmnt=$_POST['Cmnt'];

            $to='myAdredd';
            $subject='Order';
            $message="First Name: ".$Fname." "."Last Name: ".$Lname." "."\n"."E-mail: ".$email."\n"."Phone: ".$code." ".$phone."\n"."Project Name: ".$Pname."\n"."Project Type: ".$Ptype."\n"."Project Display: ".$Pdisplay."\n"."Owner: ".$Powner."\n"."Language: ".$Plang."\n"."Gender Voice: ".$Gender."\n"."Vitess: ".$Vitess."\n"."Style: ".$Style."\n"."Duration: ".$Duration."\n"."Script: "."\n\n".".$Script."."Message: ".$Cmnt."\n";

            $headers="From: ".$email;


            if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
                echo "sent";
            }else{
                echo "problem ";
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
?>
```

> Make sure configure SMTP configuration in php.ini file before run `mail()`.

SMTP configuration look like-:

[image]